# Данные поместить в коллекцию?

Tags: java, selenide

Подскажите как сделать перечисление элементов и найти указанный номер ?
Делаю с помощью selenide.

```
ElementsCollection resultElements = $$(By.className("result-table"));
```

Сюда я поместил всю таблицу. 
В таблице содержатся номера ЕИС, их надо выбрать. 
ЕИС(31908403282), вот HTML:

```
        <div class="column-main__header-item">
            <h6>
                Номер ЕИС
            </h6>
            <p>
               <a href="regNumber=31908403282" class="purchase-card" 
                target="_blank">31908403282
               </a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="column-main__header-item">
            <h6>Номер на площадке</h6>
            <p>4421/ЗКТЭ-РЖДС/19</p>
        </div>
```

Если поиск уточнить через findElement и искать по тегу:

```
ElementsCollection resultElements = $$(By.className("column-main__header-item")).findElement(tagName("a")).getText();
```

то пишет ошибку:

> "cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)   location: class
>   com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь я хочу порекомендовать вам воспользоваться любой средой разработки, которая проверяет синтаксис вашего кода, например [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows).

Конкретно про возникающую у вас ошибку, метод **$$** возвращает объект с типом **ElementsCollection**, а у него метода **findElement**, который вы пытаетесь вызвать, просто напросто не существует. Зато нужный вам метод есть у класса **SelenideElement**, хоть и называется он по другому просто **find**

В качестве решения могу предложить перебрать все имеющиеся элементы в коллекции и уже у них "искать по тегу"

```
for (SelenideElement element : resultElements) {
    element.find(/*Локатор для искомого внутреннего элемента*/).getText()
}
```

[Ссылка на документацию Selenide, рекомендую подробно ознакомиться.](https://ru.selenide.org/documentation.html)

[image: Немного об поиске внутренних элементов]

Comment: Проблему решил с помощью функции:   ElementsCollection headerItem = $$(".result-table .column-main__header-item > p > 
        a");
        for (SelenideElement number : headerItem) {
            System.out.println(number.getText());
        }

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил с помощью функции:

```
ElementsCollection headerItem = $$(".result-table .column-main__header-item > p > a"); for (SelenideElement number : headerItem) { System.out.println(number.getText()); }
```